# Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, scanf

Im trying to implement kmeans algorithm in c++, the probleme is that when i try to implement in the begining a function to intializ the means... it give me this error i searched so hard to see if i exceeded the number of array size but things looks alright and and no overflow exist. this is the code :

## header file :

```
#ifndef KM_HPP
#define KM_HPP
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define HIGH_VALUE 50

// fonction d'initialisation
void initMeans(float **, double **, int , int , int );
#endif
```

## implementation of the header file :

```
#include "km.hpp"

// fonction d'initialisation
void initMeans(float **x, double **v, int n, int p, int c){
    srand(time(0));
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) x[i][p] = rand()%c;
    v = new double*[c];
    for(int i=0; i<c; i++) v[i] = new double[p];
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) for(int j = 0; j < p; j++){
    double num = 0; int denum = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++) if(x[k][p] == i){
    num += x[k][j]; denum++;
    }
    v[i][j] = num/denum;
    }
}
```

## main file :

```
#include "km.hpp"

using namespace std;
//Les variables globale :

char nomExt[40];
int n, p, c;
float **x;
double **v;
FILE *f;

int main(){
    cout<<" donnée le nom de la fichier data :";
    cin>>nomExt;
    f=fopen(nomExt,"r");
    fscanf(f,"%d",&n);
    fscanf(f,"%d",&p);
    fscanf(f,"%d",&c);

    x = new float*[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) x[i]= new float[p];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<p;j++) fscanf(f,"%f",&x[i][j]);
    }

    initMeans(x, v, n, p, c);
    for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<p;j++) cout<<v[i][j]<<"\t";
        cout<<endl;
    }   
    for(int j=0;j<p;j++) delete [] x[j];

    delete [] x; 
    for(int j=0;j<p;j++) delete [] v[j];

    delete [] v;
        fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

x1.txt is the file that containt : number of row (n), number of column (p), number of classe,the column number for the 2D array v (c).
The file that contain the data and main.cpp, header.hpp and header.cpp(header file implementation ) and the make file  all are in the same folder.

## error message :

```
g++ -o km -O3 km.cpp main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:16:19: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  fscanf(f,"%d",&n);
                   ^
main.cpp:17:19: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  fscanf(f,"%d",&p);
                   ^
main.cpp:18:19: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  fscanf(f,"%d",&c);
                   ^
main.cpp:24:47: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   for(int j=0;j<p;j++) fscanf(f,"%f",&x[i][j]);
```

## after executing it says :

```
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped) ==> [Segmentation fault (core dumped)]
```

Comment: Compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g km.cpp main.cpp -o km` then **use the debugger** `gdb km` (and perhaps also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)). Improve your code till you get no warnings (so don't ignore result of `fscanf`!)

Comment: As a sidenote, given what you are doing you might want better random number generation than `rand()`. If you have c++11 available there's much better random number generation available to you in the standard library. Also you can use the containers such as std::array from the c++ library too and this will likely help your memory related issues.

Comment: BTW, your code is not genuine C++; use `<vector>` and [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: Please name the parameters in your function declaration to match those in the definition. What you have done is really bad practice.

Comment: I can't immediately see the direct cause, but the underlying cause of the problem is the use of fixed-sized arrays and raw pointers. Use `std::string`, `std::vector` and C++-style IO: the code will be half the size and far less error-prone.

Comment: `I'm trying to implement kmeans algorithm in c++`  If you're implementing an algorithm, I also recommend you drop the usage of pointers and use container classes such as `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc.  If you did that, you will then spend time on getting your algorithm implemented, as opposed to fighting with pointers, dynamic allocation, etc.

Comment: Thanks sirs, i got it working by calling it n = fscanf(f,"%d", &n). no warning is showing up now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing "v" into the initMeans function and initializing it there. However, the value assigned to v is not being propagated back out of the function. I would either modify the function to return v or else allocate v before calling the function.

Comment: Pefect sir i did what you said and the segmentation error has gone, But the warrning still showing up. is there any mistake in fsacnf()? is it possible to use c instruction in cpp file ?!

Comment: i fixed the warning by calling it n = fscanf(f,"%d", &n). :D

Comment: I'm glad it helped. My answer above pointed out the problem in the existing code and the minimal change to fix it. However, for "production" code I'd actually implement it using <vector> rather than raw pointers as was pointed about by posters above.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I was getting segmentation fault when I called a function that returns an integer. 
Later I figured, It was a very simple mistake that I did.
while creating an object of a class, I had written this -

Object* object;
instead of Object* object = new Object();

Hope this answer helps. 
Thanks,
Shraddha